# I am trying to grab external xml data and display it in my html page

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I am trying to grab any xml tag in this sample. But if I try grabbing anything other than the data in the first record in IE I cannot do it. What kind of javascript can I write to correct this?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Get Any XML Tag</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://imaginationeverywhere.info/jslib//dev/jquery-1.5.1.js'>
</script>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    function getData() {
        var XMLHTTPRequestObject = false;

        if (window.XMLHTTPRequest) {
            XMLHTTPRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();

        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            XMLHTTPRequestObject = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }

        if (XMLHTTPRequestObject) {
            XMLHTTPRequestObject.open('GET', 'http://imaginationeverywhere.info/xml/cd_catalog.xml', true);

            XMLHTTPRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (XMLHTTPRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHTTPRequestObject.status == 200) {
                    var xmlDocument = XMLHTTPRequestObject.responseXML;
                    displayArtist(xmlDocument);
                }
            }
            XMLHTTPRequestObject.send(null);
        }
    }

    function displayArtist(xmldoc) {
        titleName = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('TITLE');
        artistName = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ARTIST');
        countryName = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('COUNTRY');
        companyName = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('COMPANY');
        priceName = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('PRICE');
        yearName = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('YEAR'); 

        displayTitle = "The name of this song title is " + titleName[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ".";      
        displayArtist = "The name of the artist is " + artistName[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "."; 
        displayCountry = "The name of the artist country is " + countryName[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "."; 
        displayCompany = "The name of the artist company is " + companyName[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "."; 
        displayPrice = "This song costs $" + priceName[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "."; 
        displayYear= "The year this song was released " + yearName[0].firstChild.nodeValue + ".";

        var target = document.getElementById('targetDiv');
        target.innerHTML = displayTitle + "<br/>" + displayArtist + "<br/>" + displayCountry + "<br/>" + displayCompany + "<br/>" + displayPrice + "<br/>" + displayYear;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Get Tag Value</h3>

<form action="#">
    <input type="button" value='Get the name of the artist' onclick="getData()" />
</form>
<div id="targetDiv" style="width:300px; height:20px">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - it's practically all browser compatible.

Try this:

```
 function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/test.html',
        dataType : 'xml',
        success: function(data) {
            displayArtist(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: He does have jQuery included.

Comment: I am not worried about cross browser compatibility right now I am just trying to retrieve the data in IE.